# How to add horizontal padding to every line in one multi-line wrapped sentence?

Tags: css, html

This is my code:

```
<div><p><span>... highlighted text ...</span></p><p>Chapter info</p></div>
```

This is what it currently looks like:

http://i48.tinypic.com/2dqvo1i.png

Is there a way to add padding to the sides of the highlighted text? Regular padding on the SPAN doesn't work, because it only takes into account the the beginning and end of the sentence, not every line separately.

Any ideas? CSS3 code is fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for each line of the wrapped text to be padded differently? If not, why not just apply the padding to the div tag?

Comment: well i'm almost 1 year later, but I'm looking for the exactly same thing..

Comment: Check out this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34660112/483779

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After struggling for some time I found a non-quirky solution with a decent fallback for older browsers – adding two CSS3-shadows to the lines of text:

```
span {
background:#ff0;color:#000;
box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #ff0,-0.2em 0 0 #ff0;
-moz-box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #ff0,-0.2em 0 0 #ff0;
-webkit-box-shadow:0.2em 0 0 #ff0,-0.2em 0 0 #ff0;
}
```

Comment: seems to be the only way. That's perfect

Comment: This is really a great and simple solution to a common task.

Comment: Anybody has a solution for IE8 and below ?

Answer (score 4):

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Not really a solution, but does add some space before the break.

Comment: Thanks. It indeed doesn't solve the problem, but the added space does help me towards the look I'm going for.

Answer (score 1):

Just pad the "p" tags that surround the spans.  The "p" tag (unlike span) is a block-level element, so padding on the top, bottom, or sides will work as expected.

Comment: I want to pad the yellow strips of texts, so the text isn't so close to side. Example mock-up: http://i50.tinypic.com/206dlef.png

When adding the padding to the P, it just adds padding to the block as whole. However, I want to add the padding to the lines of text individually.

I'm starting to think it's not possible, because the line of text is already interpreted as ONE element, but for my idea to work, it needs to interpret each line of text separately for the horizontal padding to work.

Comment: Unfortunately though, I CAN'T create separate elements for each line, because they are created dynamically and I don't know the 'break-off' point beforehand.

Ideally there would be an :each-line pseudo-selector, that I could use to pad each line individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes).  It won't work in anything older than IE8 ([though there are some work arounds](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)), but everything else popular should be fine:

```
p span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2em;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. It just creates a block element, that doesn't clear it's siblings. Effectively, this means I get a block of yellow, instead of lines of yellow.

Comment: Oh I see.  Then I think what you want is not possible - padding by its nature applies to blocks.  Some kind of jQuery solution to add non-breaking spaces at appropriate places is the only way to go.

Comment: Too bad. I guess I'll just leave it as is then. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Marc It'll not be much use to you, but I've found out today there was a CSS property proposed which would allow you to do this, unfortunately it has since been dropped: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-background-20080910/#the-border-break

Comment: Interesting to know nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to add this to your style sector definitions:

```
span {
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Also it works for "p" (and for others) instead of "span".

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way out this misery. Worked for me. Use a button on the left like this.

```
<p>
<button class="blankspace">
</button>
<span>
</span>
</p>
```

and css it like

```
.blankspace {
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 2%;
    height: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0%;
    font-size:2px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding two CSS3-shadows as suggested, here is a much simpler answer:

use `display:block`

`<span>` is `display:inline` by default, so the borders and padding you added aren't actually affecting it's size. So only the first line is affected.

Use `display:block` on the span and `<span>` now works like `<p>` and `<div>`.

Here's a good explanation:
http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Comment: That's not the OP wants... if you do that, there's no "highlight" effect, it looks like a simple box.