# CSS: highlighted text effect

Tags: css, highlighting

I'm trying to produce a highlighted text effect with a bit of padding, but the padding is only applied to the beginning and end, not new lines.

```
#highlight {
background: rgba(255,230,0,0.5);
padding: 3px 5px;
margin: -3px -5px;
line-height: 1.7;
border-radius: 3px;
}

<span id=highlight>text<br>here</span>
```

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CNJZK/7/

Are there any pure-CSS fixes to get the internal ("sharp") edges to extend a bit farther?
i.e. like in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak2EM.jpg

Comment: Is the idea to highlight text within a larger block of text?  Your example doesn't show this but I feel that is what you are getting at.

Comment: Yes.  Perhaps this clarifies: http://jsfiddle.net/CNJZK/7/ halts the highlighting abruptly at the beginning/end of each line,  when visually, this is what I'd like to happen: http://i.imgur.com/j8mIJZS.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add horizontal padding to every line in one multi-line wrapped sentence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096916/how-to-add-horizontal-padding-to-every-line-in-one-multi-line-wrapped-sentence)

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the display on your span to inline-block:

```
#highlight {
    background: rgba(255, 230, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: -3px -5px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CNJZK/1/)**

Comment: Inline-block creates a rectangular block of highlight.  I'm looking for something that shrinks to the text (as with inline), but extends just a little farther.  Perhaps it's clearer with more text: http://jsfiddle.net/CNJZK/5/

Answer (score 3):

If you're not limited to a specific HTML standard, you could take a look at the `<mark>` tag, which was introduced with HTML5. [This site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp) gives you a quick overlook.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer:

```
p {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px yellow;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: -5px -5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

[See jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8zhr0cwb/)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is this CSS:

```
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
box-decoration-break: clone;
display: inline;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-decoration-break/

Comment: Thanks! This is the only working answer to this question here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display to `inline-block` or `block`.

```
#highlight {
    display: inline-block;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: A block creates a rectangle of highlight around the entire text (including things before/after the span).  I'd like something that fits the text, with a bit of padding at the beginning/end of lines: http://i.imgur.com/j8mIJZS.jpg

Comment: Hmmm...I can't figure out a way. Sorry.