# Comment highlight css transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the effect of when linking to a target element on another page, the target is highlighted and then fades to the default page color, aka white.

A simple example of what I'm looking for is the same as when viewing a linked comment on Stack Overflow: [CSS: highlighted text effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746649/css-highlighted-text-effect/18746683#18746683)

When you first view the comment, it is highlighted a color then transitions to white.

I'm able to make it go from white to another color, but can't seem to do the reverse, and can't find any resources helping directly.

To go from white to red, I have:

```
:target {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
```

html:

The link that takes you to the target:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 title">Additional<a target="_blank" href="/insight#additional">(?)</a></div>
```

The target being linked to:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 section-header" id="additional"><h3>Required</h3></div>
```

I'd like to do the opposite of this (make it go from red->white).

Any help would be much appreciated, as like I said, I've been looking for a solution but they're just not quite helping.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the HTML code.

Comment: Edited to show html

Comment: Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: if you use jquery the its "highlight" effect  is also helpful....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is close to the effect you described

```css
:target {
  border-radius: 3px;
  animation: highlight 1000ms ease-out;
}
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 section-header" id="additional">
  <h3>Required</h3>
</div>

<a href="#additional"> Click me </a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class to run a highlight animation.

> The `:target` CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target
>   element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

Clicking the link will change the URL's fragment identifier, so now the `:target` selector will point to the element with the matching id.

```css
:target {
  border-radius: 3px;
  animation: highlight 1000ms ease-out;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 section-header" id="additional">
  <h3>Required</h3>
</div>

<a href="#additional"> Click me </a>
```