# How to apply padding to every line in multi-line text?

Tags: html, css

I have background color applied to the `<span>` tag, there is also left and right `padding` set on it. The problem is: the `padding` is applied only to the left (beginning) and right (ending) of the `<span>`, not the left (beginning) and right (ending) of each line when the text is wrapped on several lines.

How can I apply the left and right `padding` to the **middle** lines?

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1.35em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
h1 span {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span></h1>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding padding?

Comment: Why not set up the different areas for the text in divs and just give them different background colors?

Comment: The padding is applied only to the left (beginning) and right (end) of each span, not the left (beginning) and right (end) of each line. This is working per the specification.

Comment: This is an interesting question but you should insist on the fact that the issue appears especialy when the text spans on several lines (padding left/right doesn't work)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You could use `box-decoration-break` property with value of `clone`.

> **`box-decoration-break: clone;`** Each box fragment is rendered independently with the specified border, padding and margin wrapping each fragment. The border-radius, border-image and box-shadow, are applied to each fragment independently. The background is drawn independently in each fragment which means that a background image with background-repeat: no-repeat may be repeated multiple times. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)

See the current browser support tables at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak)

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/et57j0ap/)**

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1.35em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
h1 span { 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  padding: 0 20px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span></h1>
```

Comment: I had to combine the ```box-decoration-break``` with a box-shadow technique, as outlined on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/), otherwise you get strange wrapping/alignment behaviours.

Comment: chrome and the like still seem to ignore this as a non-prefixed attribute, though.
have to use `-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;` for them.

Comment: @mtness If Chrome doesn't support it without a `-webkit` prefix, that is Chrome's problem, not yours.  Please don't clutter up your CSS with free handouts to Google.

Comment: @Jake of course - I'd like to keep my code free from this too, but in production context we have to deliver a solution which works - and educate the stakeholders about standards^^

Comment: @mtness Does "a solution which works" include a graceful fallback for browsers which don't support experimental/draft standards, or are your stakeholders only interested in a working solution for Chrome (and perhaps Edge now)? ;)

Answer (score 9):

[Multi-line-padded-text](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) by CSS Tricks to the rescue

The HTML

```
<div class="padded-multiline">
  <h1>
    <strong>
      How do I add padding to subsequent lines of an inline text element?
    </strong>
  </h1>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.padded-multiline { 
  line-height: 1.3; 
  padding: 2px 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid #c0c;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.padded-multiline h1 { 
  background-color: #c0c;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fff; 
  display: inline;
  margin: 0; 
}
.padded-multiline h1 strong { 
  position: relative;
  left: -10px; 
}
```

NB: thanks to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com) for this, and so many other tips

Comment: does it need a set width? My text can't have a fixed width

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yk0w9tg1/.
This works well when the backgrounds of each line of text touch or overlap vertically, and is very cross-browser.  If you want gaps between each line, the other solution is better and will degrade ok in *cough* IE and Edge.  The set width is for demonstration only, not required.

Comment: This does not work at all if you want to centre your multiline text.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but, you could use a `<p>` tag instead of a `<span>`, that will apply the padding to all lines.

Comment: This causes a line break. If I disable the line break with style="display:inline" the padding is back to the beginning. Since I have an icon before my text this is not working.

Comment: `<p>` is not an allowed child of `<h1>`.  Don't do this; it will break your HTML.  A better answer would have been to suggest styling the `<h1>` background, though it's clear if you read the OQ that they want to style the background for the text only (like film subitles).

Answer (score 2):

Try the below single-line statement for paragraph or label by setting `line-height`.

```
line-height: 1.3;
```

Comment: How will that help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change the element to style to `display: block` or `display: inline-block` so that you can set padding as the default `display: inline` is padding free.

Comment: By changing the display type padding is applied around the element. I added an example to clear it up.

Comment: OK, it might, as you say, be a viable solution in some circumstances.  Though changing the `display` property would have knock-on effects that mean it's not suitable in all cases.  If you add the example you said you'd added, I'll remove the downvote :)