# Prevent overlapping of two span elements

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm trying to reduce the `line-height` between two `span` tags so they appear closer together but the problem is that doing so overlaps the opacity. Is there any way to keep the opacity consistent or is there another approach I can take in adjusting the line height without the opacity overlapping?

```html
<div style="text-align:left; font-size: 20vh; color:white; line-height: 18.2vh; padding: 5vw; margin-bottom:-15px;">
  <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);">
      &nbsp;MY NAME
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);">
      &nbsp;IS ABCD&nbsp;
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to change both of the spans style position's to absolute to get the results you desire.

Please see below:

```html
<div style="text-align:left; font-size: 20vh; color:white; line-height: 18.2vh; padding: 5vw; margin-bottom:-15px;">
        <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); position: absolute">
            &nbsp;MY NAME
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); position: absolute">
            &nbsp;IS ABCD&nbsp;
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note, position absolute will affect the content flow https://jsfiddle.net/2365px9q/

Comment: Yes, Pangloss makes a great point! You will of course have to address your current needs to ensure this solution is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Pangloss. Fortunately in my case, this content is going on top of an image that spans a sizeable portion of the page, so it's the cleanest way for me to get the job done.

Comment: I'm glad this works out for you, good luck for the rest of your project!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `span` to `display: inline-block;` and using `padding` for spacing as needed.

```html
<div style="text-align:left; font-size: 20vh; color:white; line-height: 18.2vh; padding: 5vw; margin-bottom:-15px;">
  <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); padding: 10px 10px 0 10px; display: inline-block;">MY NAME</span>
  <br/>
  <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; display: inline-block;">IS ABCD</span>
</div>
```

Also, you might be interested in - [How to apply padding to every line in multi-line text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34659853/483779)