# How I can set margin between lines in one paragraph?

Tags: html, css, margin

I need to set margins between lines in one paragraph. How I can do this? I need to make something like this:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<p>Any creative project is unique 
and should be provided with 
the appropriate quality</p>
```

I tried to put each line in `<span>` and set `margin-bottom` to it, but it not working.

Comment: The `span` needs to be displayed as a block, so that vertical margin does have an effect. But then again, why not use multiple divs or paragraphs?

Comment: Similar but might not be the same as this [How to apply padding to every line in multi-line text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34659853/483779)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your whole text in a `<span>` tag and use `line-height` for margins and `padding` for spacing between text and background

***Stack Snippet***

```css
p {
  font: bold 30px Verdana;
}

span {
  background: red;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Any creative project is unique and should be provided with the appropriate quality</span></p>
```

Comment: is there any way to add padding from left and right on text?

Comment: @Belial if you want to add padding from left and right then you have to break the tags into span...:(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `<span>` with `margin` you need to set also `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to the `<span>`

```css
p {
    width: 200px;
}

p > span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Any creative project is unique</span>
  <span>and should be provided with</span>
  <span>the appropriate quality</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use `<br>` between each lines or just put a span with a `height` between each line, something like this:

```
<p>Any creative project is unique</p>
<span style="height: 10px;"></span><p>panand should be provided with</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using line-height property in your .css file referencing te element enclosing the text.